# how to use c:when condition inside value attribute of input tag?

Tags: jstl

how to use c:when condition inside value attribute of input tag?

```
<input id="textid" type="button" value="">
```

in the 'value'. what I want is

```
<c:when test="${texttest == 'Y'}"> Add </c:when>
<c:otherwise> Edit </c:otherwise>
```

Value should be 'Add' if textest is 'Y' otherwise 'Edit'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input id="textid" type="button" value="${texttest == 'Y' ? 'Add' : 'Edit'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${texttest == 'Y'}">
 Add 
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
 Edit 
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  <input id="textid" type="button" value="<c:choose> <c:when test="${texttest == 'Y'}">Add</c:when><c:otherwise>Edit</c:otherwise></c:choose>">    I can't do this. Any other way to do it?

Comment: @Jignesh, please refrain from posting code in comments. Instead, leave a small description of your problem and update your answer with relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have solved the problem by using some other way which is not relevant in this context. Thanks.